# C# How to select specific subdirectory

Tags: c#, recursion, cmd, tree, directory

im doing something similar to the cmd tree. And what im planning to check first C:\ than check the first folder in it if the first folder contains something in it go check it and so on until i get DirectoryNotFoundException. If i get such i want to skip the first folder and check the second one how to do that ?

```
static string path = @"C:\";
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            DirectoryInfo[] fileNames = di.GetDirectories();
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            DirectoryInfo[] fileNames = di.GetDirectories();
            //i need to edit the picking of filenames.Something like PickSecond/Next
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: any reasons for downvote please ?

Comment: Rather than giving you the answer I'll explain the concept to you.  You need to recursively go through each directory looking for what you are looking for.  There are plenty of examples online which I suggest you follow (e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx).  Good luck

Comment: do you really think i was going to check for all of them? that's not even possible ofc im going ot use recoursion if i put it right now it will just spam the console window with the same directory over and over until i get stackoverflowexception

Comment: i just want to skip the already checked folder/subfolder that's it

Comment: I beg to differ, your stack won't overflow if your recursion is correctly implemented unless you have a very deep folder hierarchy.  Recursion, by nature, won't recheck your already checked folder.  You need to read up that article.

Comment: It will already tried

Comment: Share your code, I can help you from there.  Simply asking generic questions like the one you have won't receive any responses, most likely why you got a downvote!

Comment: if calling a `cmd`command is an option, take a look to `tree /f`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the directory tree you can use recursion without getting any `DirectoryNotFoundException`. The following code will print to the console all the sub-directories starting from a specific path. The recursion works this way: every time a folder is found, if it's not empty then go to explore its sub-directories, otherwise go and check the next folder.

```
static void DirectoryTree(string directory, string indent = "")
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo currentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
        DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = currentDirectory.GetDirectories();

        // Print all the sub-directories in a recursive way.
        for (int n = 0; n < subDirectories.Length; ++n)
        {
            // The last sub-directory is drawn differently.
            if (n == subDirectories.Length - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(indent + "└───" + subDirectories[n].Name);
                DirectoryTree(subDirectories[n].FullName, indent + "    ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(indent + "├───" + subDirectories[n].Name);
                DirectoryTree(subDirectories[n].FullName, indent + "│   ");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Here you could probably get an "Access Denied" exception,
        // that's very likely if you are exploring the C:\ folder.
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    // Consider exploring a more specific folder. If you just type "C:\"
    // you are requesting to view all the folders in your computer.
    var path = @"C:\SomeFolder" ;
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    if(Directory.Exists(path))
        DirectoryTree(path);
    else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Directory");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```